# Ruby Websocket Issue

Tags: ruby, websocket, rubygems

I'm a little new to Ruby - please be gentle!

I have installed Ruby 1.9.3 on my Windows PC along with the DevKit. I carefully followed the instructions for setting up the devkit.

I then installed the ruby gem for simple-websocket-client:

````
C:\DevKit>gem install websocket-client-simple
Fetching: websocket-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: event_emitter-0.2.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: websocket-client-simple-0.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed websocket-1.2.2
Successfully installed event_emitter-0.2.5
Successfully installed websocket-client-simple-0.2.4
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for websocket-1.2.2...
Installing ri documentation for event_emitter-0.2.5...
Installing ri documentation for websocket-client-simple-0.2.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for websocket-1.2.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for event_emitter-0.2.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for websocket-client-simple-0.2.4...

C:\DevKit>```
````

So far so good.

Now I try to use the simple demo script shown on the github page for the gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'websocket-client-simple'
ws = Websocket::Client::Simple.connect 'wss://WN72REA4.companyname.com:8181/channel'
```

And I get:-

```
C:/Users/me/Documents/YY5/rubyscripts/websocket-demo.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Websocket (NameError)
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please? Googling around I see a few hits for this kind of issue, but they mostly read as though they were fixed by trial and error. Would appreciate any advice on where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first point isn't an answer per se, but I would like to point out that Ruby 1.9.3 is OLD. current Ruby is 2.2.3 and there's a preview 2.3.0 release... I recommend that you update to Ruby 2.2.3.

As for the answer:

You issue is related to the fact that Ruby, like most programming languages, is Case Sensitive.

You code uses Web**s**ocket instead of Web**S**ocket (notice the capital S)... it should probably read:

```
ws = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect 'wss://WN72REA4.companyname.com:8181/channel'
```

Comment: Hi Myst 
Thanks for this. I had started out with Ruby 2.2.3 but when I run into issues with gems (like this) I was advised to try 1.9.3 for compatibility.

Changing the case - as you pointed out - helps. Thank you. I should have noticed that!

My next issue is that I'm using:

    ws.on :open do 
     ws.send '{"connection-information":{}}'
    end

To send json to the server and using:-

    ws.on :message do |msg|
     puts msg.data 
    end

to process anything coming back.

At the moment there is nothing being output. Again any advice appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. You're very welcome. I would love to see if I can help with your second question, but it's very hard to read and debug your code in a comment. Maybe you could post it as a second question and post a link back here in a comment?

Comment: @user3202399 P.S., please accept any answers that answer the question. It marks the question as answered, helping future readers and it's a great way to give positive feedback.

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending you any data?

Comment: Great advice. Your answer is accepted and I will post a new question about why I get nothing back from the websocket server (works perfectly in Chrome and using Java/Jetty). Really appreciate your interest.